# member variables starting with "is" were missing when passed to feign

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I recently upgraded the **Spring Cloud Starter OpenFeign version** from **2.2.9** to **3.0.2** in a project.
Surprisingly, it was found that the **feign-core** version inside was lowered from **10.12** to **10.10.1.**

As a result, it was confirmed that **PageableSpringQueryMapEncoder(Finally call BeanQueryMapEncoder)** is used where **FieldQueryMapEncoder** was previously used.
Because of this, there was an issue that **member variables starting with "is"** were missing when passed to feign.

**Sample**

1. **Kotlin data class with member variables starting with is**
   [image]
2. **Feign Client method**
   [image]
3. **actual call url (when isEmergency value is set to true or false)**
   [image]

Comment: Wild guess here but have you tried changing from `isErmengency` to `emergency`? I bet there is something with the name here that makes Kotlin not mapping the getter "correctly" accoring to Feign.

Comment: As you said, I confirmed that it worked normally when I set it to `emergency`. However, if is 'is' attached to the member variable, it worked well before, but I left a question because it did not work when I upgraded the Spring Cloud Starter OpenFeign version.